# Time Complexity of Simplified 3-Way Partition Sort

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, space-complexity, master-theorem

Below is my algorithm that's a simplified take on Dijkstra's 3-way partition algorithm for a generic list:

```
static <T extends Comparable> void dutchSort(List<T> list, int left, int right) {
    if (left >= right) return;

    T pivot = list.get(left);

    // smaller - index of the last element smaller than pivot value
    // equal - index of the last element equal to pivot value
    // larger - index of the first element larger than pivot value
    int smaller = left-1, equal = left, larger = right;

    // before sorting is completed, 'equal' is the current value
    // much like 'i' in a for-loop
    // O(N) time
    while (equal < larger) {
        if (list.get(equal).compareTo(pivot) < 0)
            Collections.swap(list, equal, ++smaller);
        else if (list.get(equal).equals(pivot))
            equal++;
        else
            Collections.swap(list, equal, --larger);
    }

    // recursively sort smaller subarray
    dutchSort(list, left, smaller+1);

    // recursively sort larger subarray
    dutchSort(list, equal, list.size());
}
```

This is O(1) space, and I think it's O(N^N) time, but I'm not sure. [Toptal's post on 3-way QuickSort](https://www.toptal.com/developers/sorting-algorithms/quick-sort-3-way) says it's O(N^2), but the difference is my algorithm is much more naive. My thought process is: the `while` loop takes O(N) time and in the worst case (all N elements are distinct?) the problem is broken down into N subarrays of size 1.

I tried the Master Theorem, but I was not sure about any of the variable values. I think the number of subproblems is 2, each recursive call reduces the problem by a factor of 2, and merging the subproblems takes O(1) work.

All this is just educated guessing and I'm likely pretty off, so I'd really like to rigorously solve the time complexity.

Is O(N^N) time correct? And if so, why?

Thanks so much :)

Comment: It's certainly not O(1) space if you count the recursion stack. Standard references say that space is O(log n). As for the runtime complexity, why not just increment a counter each time in the `while` loop? Then run the algorithm for sample array sizes and see what you come up with? You should be able to tell the difference between O(n^2) and O(n^n) pretty easily.

Comment: Sure, that's a way to empirically determine runtime, but I was hoping to learn a more mathematically rigorous solution.

Comment: You've said you think it's n^n. If the empirical evidence agrees or disagrees, you can then figure out why. Work backwards from the answer to develop the formula.

Comment: I don't think that's very helpful or productive. I don't care about the answer. I want to learn how to find runtime for algorithms that aren't stable, e.g. whose subproblem sizes can vary. Even if I empirically got the correct runtime, then what? Empirically deducing the runtime won't teach me this because that's exactly what I don't know how to do.

Answer (score 1):

So the `while` loop is O(n) on the initial call. If we assume an array of `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, then the first time through the loop `list[equal] == pivot`, and we increment `equal`.

The second and subsequent times through the loop, `list[equal] > pivot`, so we decrement `larger` and swap with that element. When the loop is finished, you have `equal=1`, and `smaller` hasn't changed. Your recursive calls become:

```
dutchSort(list, 0, 0)
dutchSort(list, 1, n)
```

So one of the items has dropped off.

Do the same mental exercise a for a few more recursion depths, and I think you'll get an idea of how the partitioning works.

For your algorithm to be O(N^N), it would have to compare every element against every other element multiple times. But that doesn't happen because at each level of recursion you're splitting the problem into two parts. Once something is split into the left half of the array, it can't ever be compared with something that was moved into the right half of the array. So the worst case is that every element is compared against every other element. That would be O(N^2).

When all elements are equal, the algorithm is O(N).

I think the algorithm's complexity is determined by the number of unique items. It doesn't appear that initial array order will have any effect.